# Longest increasing subsequence, algorithm works wrong, no idea why

Tags: python, algorithm, list, lis

I made an implementation of *Longest Increasing Subsequence (LIS)* algorithm, as I see it would work, but results are totally mess.

```
def lis():
    #D = map(int, raw_input().split())
    D = [3, 2, 6, 4, 5, 1]
    L = [[] for i in range(len(D))]
    L[0].append(D[0])
    for i in range(len(D)):
        for j in range(0,i):
            if D[i] > D[j]:
                L[i] = L[j]
        L[i].append(D[i])
    print L
```

Returned result:

```
[[3], [2, 6, 4, 5], [2, 6, 4, 5], [2, 6, 4, 5], [2, 6, 4, 5], [1]]
```

What it should be:

```
[[3], [2], [2, 6], [2, 4], [2, 4, 5], [1]]
```

As I saw in debugger when we have:

```
L[i] = L[j]
```

Not only **`L[i]` gets new values**, but other lists on the `main (L)` list too...

I don't know how to avoid it. It looks that lists in Python are totally different than vectors languages from C family...

I'm fighting with this for a long time. Huge beer to someone who gonna find what is wrong :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you state `L[i] = L[j]` **you do not copy** the content of the list, you simply copy a reference: from now on `L[i]` and `L[j]` point to the same list and changes made through `L[i]` will reflect when you obtain `L[j]`.

A simply fix is simply to copy the list:

```
def lis():
    #D = map(int, raw_input().split())
    D = [3, 2, 6, 4, 5, 1]
    L = [[] for i in range(len(D))]
    L[0].append(D[0])
    for i in range(len(D)):
        for j in range(0,i):
            if D[i] > D[j]:
                L[i] = list(L[j])
        L[i].append(D[i])
    print(L)
```

Now hoever your algorithm does not work anymore (it was not working in the first place nevertheless). When running your (fixed) code, you get:

```
>>> lis()
[[3, 3], [2], [2, 6], [2, 4], [2, 4, 5], [1]]
```

The `3` occurs twice in the first list, you can solve this by removing the `.append` before the `for` loop. So the final version is:

```
def lis():
    #D = map(int, raw_input().split())
    D = [3, 2, 6, 4, 5, 1]
    L = [[] for i in range(len(D))] #removed the next line
    for i in range(len(D)):
        for j in range(0,i):
            if D[i] > D[j]:
                L[i] = list(L[j])
        L[i].append(D[i])
    print(L)
```

Which produces:

```
>>> lis()
[[3], [2], [2, 6], [2, 4], [2, 4, 5], [1]]
```

> **Note**: based on your comment you use [python-2.7](/questions/tagged/python-2.7), from [python-3.x](/questions/tagged/python-3.x) there is a method called `.copy()` on lists that you can call.

Comment: @Adamm: mind that your algorithm breaks (well it was already broken). I think I've added a fix.

Comment: I got small issue with: L[i] = L[j].copy(), AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'copy' but it put L[i] = list(L[j]) instead of it, is it correct?

Comment: @Adamm: yes, do you use [tag:python-2.7]? In [tag:python-3.x] `copy` is available.

Comment: Yep, 2.7 so I had to put small change, thanks for all, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

**Important Note**

The solution which is above is correct but if you try it out the result can be wrong for some instances.
For example - Longest Increasing Subsequence for numbers:

```
5 1 4 2 3 1 2 9 1
```

is

```
1 2 3 9
```

But this solution won't be on your **L** list returned by algorithm. There will be:

```
1 2 9
```

Max element from L list is needed. Then another element from D can be appended, so we have to add one more condition, here you go the correct code:

```
def lis():
#D = map(int, raw_input().split())
D = [5, 1, 4, 2, 3, 1, 2, 9, 1]
L = [[] for i in range(len(D))]
for i in range(len(D)):
    for j in range(0,i):
        if D[i] > D[j] and len(L[i]) < len(L[j])+1: #added condition
            L[i] = list(L[j])
    L[i].append(D[i])
print(L)

>>lis()
[[5], [1], [1, 4], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3, 9], [1]]
```